# Pass params through react-native navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

guys.

I'm having an issue right now, which is passing a param to a single item screen.

The problem is that I'm trying to use the `id` I'm passing to use it on a `fetch`.

I checked the docs and it has not been useful to me at all.

Here is the code:

`onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate("Item", { id: item.idItem })}`

As you can see, I'm trying to pass `id`

now, lets move on to the next screen:

`SingleItemScreen.js`

```
async fetchItem() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        try {
            fetch(`https://www.items-example.com/api/json/v2/key/lookup.php?i=${id}`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    this.setState({
                        item: responseJson, 
                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        } finally {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to pass the `id`, I'm doing this in a component and `not` in a function.

How is it possible for me to pass it and use it above the `render()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the params in the other component in the following way.

```
let {id} = this.props.route.params;
```

Do whatever you want to do with the id variable.

Comment: tried using `this.props.navigation.state.params` doesn't work. `console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params);` gives me a `LOG  undefined
undefined`

Comment: Is navigation working correctly? and where are you logging the params value?

Comment: Yes, navigation works properly. I'm logging them in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Now that I use it inside `fetchItem` I get a `WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params.id')`

Comment: Can you tell me which exact version you are using from your package.json.

Comment: `"react-navigation": "^4.3.3",`

Comment: try this, `let {id} = this.props.route.params`

Comment: `WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.route.params')`